# Getting started with Google-App-Engine Java Servlets

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am doing my first GAE project using Eclipse Lunar. On the GAE server I shall have 3 datastore objects as follows:

- Registry
- RegistrationNumbers
- Subscriptions

I have designed 18 commands to service these 3 datastore objects. Each command shall be implemented as a Java Servlet where most will have a ‘session’ object in the ‘HttpServletRequest’ parameters. The command Servlets shall be used from a Web Page [HTML] or from a Java stand alone applications...

I shall build one GAE application with an Eclipse Project name of ‘MyServlets’ and a package name of ‘myServlets’. The ‘MyServlets’ GAE application shall contain the 18 Java Servlets...

I need help getting started. I am not building a Web App. I am looking for the best way to create, debug and deploy the 18 command Servlets to the GAE server. I have successfully loaded the GAE and GWT Eclipse Plugins although I do not think I need the GWT capability.

Questions :

1) I am at the point where I need advice on what Eclipse Project should I use to build the .war file I need to deploy my servlets to the GAE server?

2) in my attempt to setup the Eclipse Lunar system for this effort I  have several plugins that I don’t think I need. If I delete them from the eclipse-Lunar/plugins folder are they gone entirely or is there a better way to get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

> I am doing my first GAE project using Eclipse Lunar. On the GAE server I > shall have 3 datastore objects as follows:
>
> Registry
>   RegistrationNumbers
>   Subscriptions
>   I now understand that a datastore should be considered as a collection of HashMaps. All my datastore HashMap keys shall commence with a GAE ID assigned to my account. The above datastore objects shall be implemented as individual HashMaps with the following codes concatenated to the GAE ID:
>    "R" - Registry; "N" - RegistrationNumbers; "S" - Subscriptions...

Next, a HashMap Unique ID is appended to each key...

> 1) I am at the point where I need advice on what Eclipse Project should I > use to build the .war file I need to deploy my servlets to the GAE
>   server?
>   After loading the GAE Eclipse Plugins I used the Eclipse menu to navigate to the new/Google/New Web ApplicationProject wizard. During the creation process, I Uncheck the “Use Google Web Toolkit” checkbox...

Comment: Looks like I messed up my answers style? I composed the answer in the text box and it looked fine. I looked for a preview option before I submitted the answer but did not find it.

Sorry !